# How Does Let's Encrypt with Traefik Generate Certificate without Request to Domain Owner Email

Tags: amazon-web-services, lets-encrypt, traefik

I recently took up the task of designing a proof of concept for a containerized microservice architecture. After looking over many different offerings, I settled on using Traefik. I have managed to get the SSL working for any application deployed and labeled by sub domain for a host.

That isn't the issue. The issue is that I don't understand the specifics of how Let's Encrypt gets a certificate issued to it. My only experience with requesting and using SSL certs comes from adding to to an ELB listener for SSL termination.

In that specific use case, I created a request which was sent to the domain registrar email for my domain. I approved the request and I get the certificate issued on AWS. For this, there was no approval. Is it because the domain already points to AWS name spaces and the ELB? If anyone has any insight into this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The certificates from Amazon Certificate Manager (*"I created a request which was sent to the domain registrar email for my domain"*) and Lets-Encrypt are Domain Validation (DV) certificates.

These certificates can be issued by confirming effective control of the hostname against which the certificate is being requested.  A certificate can't be issued without validating control of the domain name (or subdomain).

ACM uses email verification... messages are sent to the domain contacts (from WHOIS) and to several contacts at the domain name itself, asking for authorization.  An affirmative response allows the CA to assume the certificate request is authorized by the entity that controls the domain.

Lets-Encrypt, in this application, presumably uses file-based verification.  The service generates a "nonce" file -- its contents are fundamentally meaningless/useless for any other purpose, yet simultaneously unpredictable and secret.  That file is placed at a unique path on the web server specified by the service, and then the service tries to fetch the file via the Internet, possibly from multiple unknown/undocumented/geographically-dispersed source IP addresses (to reduce the likelihood that a malicious user could convince the service that the file genuinely is on the site).  If the nonce file is found and its content is intact, this allows the service to assume that the certificate request is authorized by the entity that controls the domain.

Some services (Gandi, for example) additionally support a third form of domain validation, where you are provided with nonce values that you use to create a specific DNS record at the site.  The existence of this unpredictable record with its unpredictable content allows the service to conclude that the certificate request is authorized by the entity that controls the domain.

Domain Validation is the lowest level of validation of web site certificates, and unlike certificates with higher levels of validation, the resulting certificate itself does not identify the actual organization that the certificate was issued to, because the organization was not actually validated -- only control of the domain was.

A relatively new standard, [Certificate Authority Authorization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_Certification_Authority_Authorization) DNS records will prevent issuance of certificates by a CA not specifically listed, if a CAA record is present in the domain's DNS records.

---

Update: On 2017-11-22, ACM [announced](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/11/aws-certificate-manager-easier-certificate-validation-using-dns/) that it had added the capability to do domain validation via DNS, which is the "third" option I mentioned, above.  At the time the question was originally asked and answered,  ACM only supported email validation.